# Calling sub routine or function in VB 6 application via console

Tags: vb6, console, console-application

I want to make simple app that has 1 method and 2 parameters in it and
the app can be launched via console/CMD like this:

```
name_of_app.exe name_of_method param1 param2
```

example: 
I have an app that named `myApp.exe` that have a method like this

```
  Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")

        Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
        Dim total As Integer
        x = Console.ReadLine()
        y = Console.ReadLine()
        total = plus(x, y)
        Console.WriteLine("result: " & total)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Private Function plus(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + y
    End Function
End Module
```

So in the console/cmd I just call that function like this

```
myApp.exe plus 3 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: i already made a module like this below so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strCommand As String
    Dim s() As String
    Dim spliter As String
    Dim returnValue As Variant
    strCommand = Command
    Do While InStr(1, strCommand, "  ", vbTextCompare) > 0
        strCommand = Replace(strCommand, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    spliter = " "
    s = Split(strCommand, spliter)
    returnValue = CallByName(Me, s(0), VbMethod, Val(s(1)), Val(s(2)))
    MsgBox returnValue
End Sub

Public Function Plus(ByVal Param1 As Variant, ByVal Param2 As Variant)
    Plus = Param1 + Param2
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for your answer iman, but it has an error, it says "Error 1 'Me' is not valid within a Module". 
Can you explain the codes that you make? thanks anyway

Comment: you should paste code in 'Form' because 'CallByName' method only fire in Objects like Form or Class.

Comment: how to run it in cmd?

Comment: can u upload the project that can run in VB 2010?

Comment: you shoud Make exe from vb6 project and in cmd or Run call like this 'c:\myapp.exe plus 3 4'